# Change class form c("Labeled", "Date") to "Date" in mutate (or similiar dplyr) statement

Tags: r

I have a dataframe produced by `sasxport.get` from the `Hmisc` package and as a result all columns have two classes: "Labeled" and their ordinary class.

In general this is a good thing, I like the labels. But sometimes, for `Date` variables I need to simplify the class form `c("Labeled", "Date")` to just `Date` in order to be able to use them in an `if_else` statement from the `dplyr` package.

Now I know how to do this in the 'old school way'

```
class(variable) <- "Date"
```

My question is: can this also be done by a `mutate` statement (or similar)?

Just for esthetic reasons. It just looks kind of silly to have an endless string of 'tidyverse'-style statements with `%>%`s between them, then interrupt this for the stupid 20th century style

```
class(mydataframe$annoyingvariable) <- "Date"
```

and then continue again with `mydataframe <- mydataframe %>%`

There are lots of questions on this site about using `mutate` to change class, but the answers always apply functions like `as.factor` or `as.numeric`. However, `as.Date` will just preserve the label (so so nothing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`` `class<-` `` and `` `oldClass<-` `` are the functions behind `class(x) <- value` and `oldClass(x) <- value` syntax. So you can do this:

```
library(Hmisc)
library(magrittr)

variable <- as.Date("2023-06-07")
label(variable) <- "a label"

variable %>% `oldClass<-`("Date") %>% class
#[1] "Date"
```

I wouldn't be surprised if some tidyverse package defined a function `` setclass <- `class<-` ``.

By the way, personally, I would just state:

"It just looks kind of silly to have an endless string of 'tidyverse'-style statements with %>%s."